# Is this a pandas bug or feature?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am trying to fill a pandas series with a constant, provided some condition is met. As a simplified test case I will use the following:

```
'-'*pd.Series([True]*5, dtype=bool)
```

This results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-0e3400ddc239> in <module>()
----> 1 '-'*pd.Series([True]*5, dtype=bool)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(left, right, name)
    529             if hasattr(lvalues, 'values'):
    530                 lvalues = lvalues.values
--> 531             return left._constructor(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
    532                                      index=left.index, name=left.name,
    533                                      dtype=dtype)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    476                 result = np.empty(len(x), dtype=x.dtype)
    477                 mask = notnull(x)
--> 478                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], y)
    479             else:
    480                 raise TypeError("{typ} cannot perform the operation {op}".format(typ=type(x).__name__,op=str_rep))

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

If I however do the following:

```
'-'*pd.Series([True]*5, dtype=bool).astype(object)
```

I get the expected:

```
0    -
1    -
2    -
3    -
4    -
dtype: object
```

Can somebody explain to me what is going on? Am I maybe choosing an awkward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are choosing an awkward way to do this by using the `*` operator. Might it be easier to use [pandas.Series.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)?

eg.

```
pd.Series([True]*5,dtype=bool).map( lambda x : '-' if x else None )
```

If you're set on using the `*` operator I note that you can use it on two vectors, instead of on a scalar + vector:

```
my_filter = pd.Series([True]*5,dtype=bool)
pd.Series('-',index=my_filter.index) * my_filter
```

Or (as you more or less identified) it works if you adjust the `dtype` up front:

```
'-' * pd.Series([True]*5,dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not a fan of this solution for layout reasons. In my code my approach is supposed to look like this: `'-'*myBoolSerVar`. It is immediately clear what is happening: the `'-'` leads the expression! Your solution kind of buries the lead by having `'-'` in the middle somewhere: `myBoolSerVar.map( lambda x : '-' if x else None )`. Also I think by using map, the operation is no longer vectorized and thus slower than could be?

Comment: Pandas' inbuilt `map` is explicitly for vectorised calculation across a series. I can't speak for your coding style, it's a matter of taste. Again I prefer to use the explicit `map` method when transforming one series into another series.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `map` being vectorized. I agree coding style is a matter of preference. Mine may be non-pythonic as it stems from using Matlab. That being said, any idea why my approach only work after casting `myBoolSerVar` to `object`?

Comment: I'm afraid not -- it certainly looks like you've bumped into an ugly implementation detail.

Comment: I've edited this answer with the best available solutions. The short answer is that there is no implementation in pandas for `[object scalar] x [object vector]`